# Passing uber authentication from one route to another with nodejs

Tags: node.js, uber-api

So I'm using the uber API in nodejs trying to use uber services such as price and time estimates, along with ride requests through my app.

I am able to authorize the user and return with a callback url, but I don't know how to pass the created access token or product_id to the specific /requests or /estimates routes.

Here's my server file:

```
//  Authenticate uber login with scopes
app.get('/v1.2/login', function(request, response) {
    var url = uber.getAuthorizeUrl(['profile', 'request', 'places', 
'all_trips', 'ride_widgets']);
    response.redirect(url);
    log(url);
    // User can manually go to authorization @ 
https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?
client_id=LJGpana69PX47lPLFP5PpIdySYT5CT-G&response_type=code
});


//  Redirect script to authorize uber profile with oAuth 2.0
app.get('/v1.2/callback', function(request, response) {
    uber.authorizationAsync( {
        authorization_code: request.query.code
    })
    .spread(function(access_token, refresh_token, authorizedScopes, 
tokenExpiration) {
    // store the user id and associated access_token, refresh_token, 
scopes and token expiration date
        log('New access_token retrieved: ' + access_token);
        log('... token allows access to scopes: ' + authorizedScopes);
        log('... token is valid until: ' + tokenExpiration);
        log('... after token expiration, re-authorize using 
refresh_token: ' + refresh_token);

        var query = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
        return uber.products.getAllForLocationAsync(query.lat, 
query.lng);
    })
    .then(function(res) {
        log(res);
        // redirect the user back to your actual app
        response.redirect('../Client/index.html');
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
});


app.post('/v1.2/requests', function(request, response) {
    // extract the query from the request URL
    //var query = url.parse(request.url, true).query;

    uber.requests.createAsync({
        "fare_id": j,
        "start_latitude": request.query.lat,
        "start_longitude": request.query.lng,
        "end_latitude": request.query.goalat,
        "end_longitude": request.query.goalng
    })
    .then(function(res) { 
        log(res); 
        uber.requests.getCurrentAsync()
        .then(function(res) { 
            log(res); 
            res.send('got it');
        })
        .error(function(err) { 
            console.error(err); 
        });
    })
    .error(function(err) { 
        console.error(err); 
    });

});
```

Like I said before I am just at a loss of passing the access token and getting the product_id to the request route or others. The documentation doesn't really give any examples.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, by executing [`uber.authorizationAsync`](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber#step-two-receive-redirect-and-get-an-access-token), you already get the access_token. It's a property stored in the wrapper object and you can retrieve it with [`uber.access_token`](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber/blob/master/lib/Uber.js#L48).

As for your second question, you already obtain the available product IDs with `uber.getAllForLocationAsync`. However, you don't cache them for your requests call. I'd recommend to split out the product ID call [as documented in the README for node-uber](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber#step-three-make-http-requests-to-available-resources). With that, in the request's method, you call the product method and get the JSON response that includes the product IDs you need to make a request.

Comment: It still says my route can't be reached when I try to reach the route, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how you define and access the route - sounds like a general NodeJS/ExpressJS question :)